# What does pkgconfig(<PACKAGENAME>) entry means on CentOS packages site?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum

For example `pkgconfig(libnm-glib)` here

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libnm-gtk-devel-1.8.6-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

I have one machine which is unable to

```
yum install libnm-gtk
```

saying it depends on `libnm-glib` without any explanation why doesn't it download dependency as usual?

Answer (score 0):

`pkgconfig(libnm-glib)` as a package requirement means that the depending package needs a package providing the `pkgconfig` configuration file for `libnm-glib`, *i.e.* `libnm-glib.pc`. The appropriate package [will show `pkgconfig(libnm-glib)` in its “Provides”](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/NetworkManager-glib-devel-1.18.8-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html).

Such dependencies are only useful for development packages and aren’t relevant for `libnm-gtk` (the runtime package).

As for why `libnm-gtk` can’t be installed, that is a different question and probably requires more investigation. The relevant package for `libnm-glib` is `NetworkManager-glib`.